# Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.Net.URLClient.TNameValuePair>' and 'TNameValuePair' when using basic authentication header

Tags: android, delphi, httprequest, basic-authentication, pascal

I've been trying to use the `NetHTTPRequest` & `NetHTTPClient` components in Delphi to issue a basic authentication request, but I've been having trouble with the `NetHTTPRequest.Get` method...

Basically, the method needs three parameters, namely `URL(String)`, memory stream, and the header of the type `TNetHeader`.

I don't know why, but when I try to pass my newly created header, I get the error mentionned in the title, namely

> `Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.Net.URLClient.TNameValuePair>' and 'TNameValuePair'`

I don't know if I have to cast, and If I have to, cast it to what?

Of course, If I don't pass on the basic auth header, the server just returns a 401 because it doesn't see any credentials or header to decode...

Here is the code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTPResponseString: String;

begin
  if IsLoggedIn = False then
  begin
    if Edit2.Text = '' then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Password cannot be empty');
      exit;
    end;

    BasicAuth := username + ':' + Edit2.Text; // + '£';
    AuthentificationPacket := EncodeBase64(UTF8Bytes(utf8string(BasicAuth)));

    HTTPHeader := TNetHeader.Create('Authorization: Basic', AuthentificationPacket);

    try
      HTTPResponseLogin := NetHTTPRequest1.Get(HTTPLoginRequest, nil, HTTPHeader);

      ShowMessage(HTTPResponselogin.ContentAsString());
      IsLoggedIn := True;

    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage(E.Message);

    end;

    Button1.Text := 'LOG OFF';
  end
  else if IsLoggedIn then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := '';
    Edit2.Text := '';
    username := '';
    password := '';
    tagid := '';

    Button1.Enabled := False;
    Button1.Text := 'LOG IN';
    IsLoggedIn := False;

    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    IdleTimer := 0;

    Application.OnIdle := nil;
  end;

end;
```

The problematic line is of course, the `NetHTTPRequest1.Get(HTTPLoginRequest, nil, HTTPHeader);`

Where `HTTPHeader` is marked as incompatible...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error message says that your HTTPHeader has to be an Array of NetHeader, and not a single NetHeader.

Comment: The message is just telling you that the compiler expects one type, and you provided a different, incompatible type. It's a type mismatch. You can do a lot by trying to understand error messages. In this case, you should read the documentation for this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [declaration](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPRequest.Get) of `TNetHTTPRequest.Get()` more carefully:

```pascal
function Get(const AURL: string; const AResponseContent: TStream = nil; const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil): IHTTPResponse;
```

The 3rd parameter takes a [`TNetHeaders`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.URLClient.TNetHeaders)(plural), but you are passing it a [`TNetHeader`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.URLClient.TNetHeader) (singular) instead. It wants an *array* of name/value pairs.

Also, `Basic` is not part of an `Authorization` header's name, it is part of its value instead.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BasicAuth, AuthentificationPacket: string;
  HTTPHeader: TNetHeader;
begin
  if not IsLoggedIn then
  begin
    if Edit2.Text = '' then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Password cannot be empty');
      Exit;
    end;

    BasicAuth := username + ':' + Edit2.Text; // + '£';
    AuthentificationPacket := 'Basic ' + EncodeBase64(UTF8Bytes(UTF8String(BasicAuth)));

    HTTPHeader := TNetHeader.Create('Authorization', AuthentificationPacket);

    try
      ShowMessage(NetHTTPRequest1.Get(HTTPLoginRequest, nil, [HTTPHeader]).ContentAsString());
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    IsLoggedIn := True;
    Button1.Text := 'LOG OFF';
  end
  else
  begin
    Edit1.Text := '';
    Edit2.Text := '';
    username := '';
    password := '';
    tagid := '';

    Button1.Enabled := False;
    Button1.Text := 'LOG IN';
    IsLoggedIn := False;

    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    IdleTimer := 0;

    Application.OnIdle := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`TNetHTTPRequest.CustomHeaders`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPRequest.CustomHeaders) property instead of the `AHeaders` parameter:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BasicAuth: string;
begin
  if not IsLoggedIn then
  begin
    if Edit2.Text = '' then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Password cannot be empty');
      Exit;
    end;

    BasicAuth := username + ':' + Edit2.Text; // + '£';
    NetHTTPRequest1.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + EncodeBase64(UTF8Bytes(UTF8String(BasicAuth));

    try
      ShowMessage(NetHTTPRequest1.Get(HTTPLoginRequest).ContentAsString());
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    IsLoggedIn := True;
    Button1.Text := 'LOG OFF';
  end
  else
  begin
    Edit1.Text := '';
    Edit2.Text := '';
    username := '';
    password := '';
    tagid := '';

    Button1.Enabled := False;
    Button1.Text := 'LOG IN';
    IsLoggedIn := False;

    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    IdleTimer := 0;

    Application.OnIdle := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is exactly what I was looking for :) Btw, I've been reading a lot of your answers and resources posted throughout the years, and I have to say, you're a real legend of a delphi dev :) Keep it up!